# Not able to locate element in appium by using xpath ends-with for iOS app created using react native

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I am automating the flow of iOS app made using react native.

I am able to find elements by XPath normally but when trying the ends-with syntax, it is unable to find the element.

I am using python language, below is the example of code snippet I am using:
`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[ends-with(@name, 'locatorValue')]")`

I tried to find the solution or example syntax to check if I am doing something wrong, but most of the times I was getting examples of Android only and also the syntax which I am using seems to be proper to me as per my understanding.

Is it a limitation that I can't use ends-with xpath for iOS app made using react native, or am I missing something here?

Kindly request to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use iOS NSPredicate expression like,
 `self.driver.find_element_by_ios_predicate("name ENDSWITH 'locatorValue'")`

This should work for you.

To know more about iOS predicates, check [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-predicate).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in above comment `iOSNsPredicateString` can be used this way

```
self.driver.find_element_by_ios_predicate("type =='XCUIElementTypeOther' AND name ENDSWITH[c] 'locatorValue' AND enabled==1")
```